# What is needed to access a CCTV system (based on a static IP)?

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, static-ip, cctv

I was wondering (since I'm a beginner or intermediate in computer networks), what do you need to access a CCTV system. Let's suppose we have a CCTV system configured with an username and password on a static IP. Each camera is accessed with a different port. 
Now my question is:
 Can I access a camera (or the system itself), if I know the static IP, username and password (just with these only), or is there needed something else? When I say something else, I mean if it's needed to open a firewall port from the router, or if it is needed to configure a DNS or something else. Also I was wondering, can this be accessed from a normal web browser, or is it needed a program?
Thanks in advance!

P.S.
Sorry if I was unclear. Question will be edited if needed.

Comment: Do you have a particular model in mind? Different equipment will have different answers depending on the feature set of the product.

Comment: Are you trying to access it from the inside or outside?  Do you view it with a program or browser now?  You have to be a *lot* more descriptive to get an answer.

Comment: @JasonAller is right, without a make and model, it would be impossible to give a correct answer.  Even *with* the make and model, it might be impossible to answer correctly.  Is this a COTS system, or custom built using an API?

Comment: @JasonAller, not a particular system. Just in general... Like, if this is build on a static IP, and you know the IP, username and password, can you access it anywhere?

Comment: @Keltari, I'm not trying anything. Just wanted to know if you have the password, username and IP, can you access it anywhere without any tool? Or do you also need to make that IP accessible for the public to access a username and password interface?

Comment: @ErlisD. Again, its *impossible* to say.  You are asking a yes or no question, without enough information.  CCTV systems are different.  Its like asking are cats furry.  Most are, except the ones that arent.

Comment: You've asked specific questions like about how one could access it, but aren't supplying enough information about the cameras or the network they are on. I know of cameras that have built in web servers for instance that you could use a web browser to access, and others where you'd need proprietary software.

Comment: @JasonAller Precisely! So, it can be accessed through a web server. But to access that web server you need that IP address to be a public IP (or maybe also using a domain?), and after that it's asked for the credentials. But to access a camera, is it not needed also a software where you can stream the videos?? 
I'm just asking theoretically, not for a specific system...

Comment: A VPN could allow access to non-public IP ranges. If the camera has its own web server then it may be streaming the video via any number of protocols including some where the browser might not even need a plugin.

Comment: @JasonAller Good! Everything's clear now! Thanks a bunch!  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're accessing the cameras from the same network (ie. your local network) then the IP and credentials are likely enough, but you'd need to refer to the documentation for your cameras to know for certain.

If you're attempting to access the cameras from the Internet then you'll need to make sure the IP is a non-private address, and that any devices sitting between the cameras and the Internet (external firewalls or NAT routers for example) are configured to allow traffic from the Internet to be passed on to the ports used by the cameras.

The specifics of configuring this will depend on:

1. The specific network devices sitting between the cameras and the Internet.
2. The specific model of camera will determine which ports or protocols need to be accessible.

Without this information it's not possible to give a more accurate answer.